# How to return class - type in a method

Tags: java, class, methods, junit, return-type

I have a class

```
public class Engine {

    Double engineSize;
    public Engine(){
        this.engineSize = 1.0;
    }
    public Double getEngineSize() {

        return engineSize;
    }
}
```

I have another class:

```
public class ModelT {

    public Engine getEngine() {

        return null;
    }}
```

Now I want to pass this test:

```
@Test

public void shouldHaveTheCorrectEngineSize(){
    assertThat(modelT.getEngine().getEngineSize(), is(1.0));
}
```

I have the difficulty how can I return the Engine type in a method, I tried several ways but knowledge is limited because I am beginner to java.. Could you please tell me how could i do this? and what is the name of concept that i could further read on..

Comment: Why does `getEngine` return a null object? You can't do any method calls on that.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to answer your question. You return an Engine type (object) by returning an Engine type object. Just like you return a Double in `getEngineSize` you can do the same by returning an Engine in `getEngine`

Comment: I kept it null for now as a question, that how could I return the type of Engine instead of null here and to get the value of getEngineSize through this method and return it as Engine object... I am a beginner and its very confusing for me...

Comment: If you have trouble doing things like that, I would highly recommend not to start by using JUnit, but by studying some tutorials. For example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/

Comment: @tnw but how could get the value of 'getEngineSize()' through 'getEngine()' and return it as engine type?

Answer (score 2):

You need to store an instance of Engine in your ModeT class:

```
public class ModelT {

   private Engine eng;      
  ModelT( Engine eng){
       engine = eng;
  }

    public Engine getEngine() {

        return eng;
    }}
```

then in you Main - create an Engine object and pass in to modelt:

```
 Engine eng = new Engine();
  ModelT car = new Modelt(eng);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i'm not understanding your question but your test never will return ok because in your ModelT method getEngine you are returning a null..

Try with below code:

```
public class ModelT {
    public Engine getEngine() {
        return new Engine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This test will never pass, because you return `null` in the `getEngine()` method. 
If you call `getEngineSize()` on `null`, you will receive a `NullPointerException`

You need to do something like this:

```
public class ModelT {

    public Engine getEngine() {

        return new Engine();
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use your `Engine`.

Because of your questoin about how to learn the basics in Java, I would recommend you the [Java-Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/) from Oracle directly.

Comment: how could I return the value of public double getEngineSize() in the class ModelT?

Comment: You have to understand that the getEngineSize returns a property of the Engine. So your Engine already knows the size. So you could just change the return-type from Engine to Double, because the EngineSize is a double.

Comment: If would do that I would fail the test because; in the test it shows this error then;The method getEngineSize() is undefined for the type Double

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to see what you're trying to achieve.

You could look into instanceof to get the class of Engine.

You might want to look into inheritance and the various ways you can relate classes.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your **getter** will make more sense if you associate the `Engine` class with the `ModelT`
and by associating I mean using a [Composition relationship](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php)

```
public class ModelT {
    private Engine myEngine;
    //some setter, DI or Constructors here 
    public Engine getEngine() {

        return myEngine;
    }
}
```

---

> *how could I return the value of public double getEngineSize() in the
>    class ModelT??*

you have somewhere:

```
ModelT foo = new ModelT();
Engine e = foo.getEngine();
double s = e.getEngineSize();
```

Comment: how could I return the value of public double getEngineSize() in the class ModelT?

Comment: @Tayyab I#ve updated the answer... you have an object of the class ModelT, inside is an Engine and inside a double... so you can call getters until you get that value :)

Comment: public Engine getEngine() {
     ModelT foo = new ModelT();

     Engine e = foo.getEngine();
     double s = e.getEngineSize();
        return s;
    }